# What does this statement mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently still getting to know more about Haskell, under the topic of **Pattern Matching**, what does it mean by `_ && _ = False` in Haskell? I came across this statement in one of the lecture slides, like what does it mean by the underscores? Thanks again!

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure without actually looking at the lecture (since you've provided no other context in your question), but I suspect that the underscores (or underlines, if you will) are there as merely placeholders for two boolean expressions.  Check with your instructor.

Comment: It is not "difficult to know for sure"; this is a well-documented language feature.

Answer (score 10):

The underscores are wildcards. That is, they match any value, but do not bind the value to a name. A common example of this usage is:

```
True && True = True
_ && _ = False
```

Answer (score 5):

Underscores means a *wildcard*. It binds with any value. It thus means that for any value for the left and right operand for the given type of the function, it will fire that clause, and thus return `False`.

One can thus define [**`(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-38--38-) with:

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && True = True
_ && _ = False
```

The real implementation of `(&&)` is however lazy in its second parameter, and is [implemented as <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Classes.html#line-232):

> ```
> -- | Boolean \"and\"
> (&&)                    :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
> True  && x              =  x
> False && _              =  False
> ```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate on the part when you said "fire that clause"? I still don't quite get it, thanks a bunch!! @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @hamburgerwhoselflearns: it means that it returns the expression at the right side of the `=`. So if you write `True && False`, it will evaluate the clauses top to bottom. The first one will not match (since there are two `True`s), so it looks for the next one, and that pattern will "fire", so it will return `False`.

Comment: So basically an underscore can also represents any non-empty list as well right?

Comment: @hamburgerwhoselflearns An underscore would match a non-empty list, yes; but that question is a bit strange here, because the type of `(&&)` says that its arguments are not lists, so you would never attempt to match a list against the pattern `_` for this code snippet.